# Port forward through Wireguard tunnel

Tags: vpn, port, ip-forwarding

I have a raspi connected to the Internet with a Wireguard roadwarrior tunnel to the office.

The raspi should forward traffic at the "raspi Intranet" to the office net to a specific server.
Also raspi has access to the specific server at port 3000.

"other clients in Raspi Net (port 3000)" ->"raspi:3000"-> Tunnel->office->Server:3000

As example:
Raspi Intranet eth0 has 192.168.13.201,Tunnel Address wg0 has 10.10.10.15, Office Server daemon for Port 3000 has 192.168.1.5:3000

I had try this without success:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:3000
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.5 --dport 3000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with this rules:

```
 iptables -P FORWARD DROP
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 3000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -d 192.168.1.5 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.15
```

The primary problem was the last rule. I must change the --to-source Adress to the tunnel Adapter Adress and not the eth0 one.

Bfo

Comment: Why not route all traffic? NAT is a ugly hack, ad as you have private IP's on internal net and wg net, you can route traffic as you want, and not have to rely on nat.

Comment: Because i will not route "all" traffic trough the tunnel.